# IIS 7 URL Rewriting Module: Custom response and Post Data

Tags: http, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I need to create a rule that rewrites an URL to a new one with code 301 and at the same time brings a Custom Response with code 200 (HTTP OK) also redirecting the data submitted by POST. I did this with two rules, however the data submitted is lost along the way during the redirection.

Comment: POST data will be lost on 301 Redirect -- that is how it works in browser.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that! So I solved it by using the 307 redirection (Temporary redirection), which unlike the other redirections, doesn't convert the post request to get.

Comment: You should post your fix as the answer and accept it so the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by using the 307 redirection (Temporary redirection), which unlike the other redirections, doesn't convert the post request to get.

Thank you!